# Orchard CMS Blog Spam Comments

Tags: orchardcms

I have an Orchard CMS with a blog as part of the site, there was no spam protection on the site for around 4months and during this time the blog was hit with over 28,000 comments, this is causing the site to run extremely slow and in turn the site is crashing or timing out.

Any ideas how to remove the blog without the site crashing? The site is hosted with Arvixe.

Comment: Deleting the blog in the backend actually crashes your site?

Comment: Doesn't crash the site, it times out. Finally got the hosting company to increase the virtual memory so I can now delete the blogs without it timing out. :)